# Azure Service Bus: ignoring messages sent by me

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I have a series of software agents installed on various machines communicating via Azure Service Bus. Each agent may be both a publisher and subscriber.

Is there any built in mechanism in Azure Service Bus for a sender not to receive the messages back from the bus (e.g. some sort of 'echo cancellation')?

Example: if A, B, and C are the agents, what I would like to achieve is that a message sent by A is delivered to B and C without the loopback to A.

I guess I could get by with filters, but I am wondering whether there's something simpler built-in in the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the issuer name (which could be the same for all your agents) the Service Bus can't know that there is a releationship between the publisher and the subscriber (ie: that they're the same agent).

That's why I think Filters are the easiest way to implement what you're trying to do. And Filters are already very simple/easy to work with, no?

Comment: Yes, filters seem easy (I haven't tried using them yet). But that would force me to introduce some sort of identification (e.g. a name) for each agent to match against in the filter. Something that I didn't need up until now.

Comment: From your question I understand that each agent could be a subscriber, so you created 3 subscriptions each with a specific name. Why not identify the agents with that name?

Comment: Yes, that could work too... It would couple sending code with receiving code a bit more but I guess I can live with that ;) Grazie.